# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException : ERROR : relation does NOT exist PreparedStatement.executeQuery ()

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

For some strange reason hibernate generated query not working with postgres, it tells it cannot find relation/table even though there is valid table `film_actor` in `dvdrental` schema? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506805/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-relation-app-user-does-not-exist) did not help.

**Exception:**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException : ERROR : relation "dvdrental.film_actor" does NOT exist PreparedStatement.executeQuery () FAILED !
```

**HQL**

```
Query searchQuery = session.createQuery("select film from Film as film " +
                    "inner join film.actors  as a " +
                    "inner join film.categories as c " +
                    "where c.categoryId=:categoryId " +
                    "and film.language.id=:languageId " +
                    "and film.releaseYear=:releaseYear " +
                    "and a.actorId=:actorId");
```

**Generated SQL**

```
SELECT
    film0_.film_id AS film_id1_8_,
    film0_.description AS descript2_8_,
    film0_.language_id AS languag12_8_,
    film0_.last_update AS last_upd3_8_,
    film0_. LENGTH AS length4_8_,
    film0_.rating AS rating5_8_,
    film0_.release_year AS release_6_8_,
    film0_.rental_duration AS rental_d7_8_,
    film0_.rental_rate AS rental_r8_8_,
    film0_.replacement_cost AS replacem9_8_,
    film0_.special_features AS special10_8_,
    film0_.title AS title11_8_
FROM
    dvdrental. PUBLIC .film film0_
INNER JOIN dvdrental.film_actor actors1_ ON film0_.film_id = actors1_.film_id
INNER JOIN dvdrental. PUBLIC .actor actor2_ ON actors1_.actor_id = actor2_.actor_id
INNER JOIN dvdrental.film_category categories3_ ON film0_.film_id = categories3_.film_id
INNER JOIN dvdrental. PUBLIC .category category4_ ON categories3_.category_id = category4_.category_id
WHERE
    category4_.category_id = 1
AND film0_.language_id = 1
AND film0_.release_year = 2016
AND actor2_.actor_id = 2;
```

**This query works fine:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
film f
INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
LIMIT 100;
```

The Film entity annotation based mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "film_actor", catalog = "dvdrental", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "film_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Actor> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

    public void setActors(Set<Actor> actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }
```

**Solution/Hack:**

After commenting `/*catalog = "dvdrental"*/` the problem went away.

Comment: A catalog is not a schema, it's the next level up. See [What's the difference between a catalog and a schema in a relational database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022755/whats-the-difference-between-a-catalog-and-a-schema-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Have to specifiy the schema, not the catalog.
[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Table.html)

In the generated SQL-Query you search for a table `dvdrental.PUBLIC.film` and i assume, that only `dvdrental.film` exists.

Updated Film entity annotation based mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "film_actor", schema= "dvdrental", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "film_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id",
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Actor> getActors() {
    return actors;
}

public void setActors(Set<Actor> actors) {
    this.actors = actors;
}
```